# in app purchase NSTableCellView

Tags: swift, macos, uitableview, nstableview, storekit

in iOS apps i used this method to set a checkmark on a cell if an in app purchase was previously purchased. Here is the code:

```
class ProductCell: UITableViewCell{
static let priceFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.formatterBehavior = .behavior10_4
formatter.numberStyle = .currency

return formatter
}()

var product: SKProduct? {
      if myproduct.store.isProductPurchased(product.productIdentifier) {


    accessoryType = .checkmark
    accessoryView = nil
    detailTextLabel?.text = ""
  }
 }
```

My problem is that i can't find an accessoryType correspondent for macOS Development. Can anyone help me?

Comment: There is no macOS equivalent of accessoryType. Use a checkbox or an image of a check mark.

Comment: How i can programmatically put a checkbox for all tableview cell index?

Comment: Add the checkbox in IB and switch it on/off. Or add an image view in IB and switch isHidden on/off.

Comment: thank you, i will try it